# Indicating mandatory field without labels

Tags: forms, gui-design, textbox, mandatory-fields

I have multiple forms in my application. I have used minimalistic view where there are no explicit labels for fields. For example, check wireframe displayed below:
[image]

Here First Name, Last Name, and Username are mandatory fields.

However, due to "some" guidelines, I have to mention which fields are mandatory before the user would fill out the form.

**What is the best way to indicate that these fields are mandatory?**

I do not want to add labels to the text boxes just for this purpose, as I have used the same styling everywhere.

Here are two options that I tried:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even you don't use a separate HTML element as label, the placeholder has the same role in your case, so the first option is the most natural.

Please see an example from the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout):

[image]